# get all data with SUM of VALUE in a date range and Sum of value < date in a single query in LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I need to make a query of sum of values in a date range and the sum of values before a particular date in a single query.

````
```SELECT s.*,
           (SELECT SUM(s1.amount) 
        FROM sales s1
            WHERE `dates` BETWEN  $start AND $enddate as salesrange,
           (SELECT SUM(s2.amount) 
        FROM sales s2
            WHERE `dates` < $start  salesyesterday
FROM sales s
````

I did like this

```
$categories = account::leftJoin('regularvoucherentrydetails', 
              function ($join){
              $join->on('regularvoucherentrydetails.account_name',
              '=' , 'accounts.id') ;
              $join->whereBetween('regularvoucherentrydetails.dates', 
              ['2021-08-01','2021-08-31']);
              $join- 
              >select(DB::raw('sum(regularvoucherentrydetails.amount) 
              as sums'),'regularvoucherentrydetails.debitcredit');
              },
              function ($joins){
              $joins-> 
              where('regularvoucherentrydetails.dates','<',
              '2021-08-01');
              $joins->
              select(DB::raw('sum(regularvoucherentrydetails.amount) 
              as sum'),'regularvoucherentrydetails.debitcredit');
              })->
              select('accounts.id','accounts.name','accounts.seqnumber',
              'accounts.accounttype')-> 
             groupBy('accounts.id','accounts.name',
           'accounts.seqnumber',
            'regularvoucherentrydetails.debitcredit',
            'accounts.accounttype')
            ->orderBy('accounts.fullcode','asc')
            ->get();
```

How can I do in laravel

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched the docs? We will not teach you "How to". You need to do some research and try to write the code yourself. If you get stuck we'll be glad to help. quick tip: `DB:raw`

Comment: What is the reason to receive all columns from `sales` if you need in SUMs only?

Comment: I need almost all columns and the SUM column in different condition